# How to start a process in background from a Python script and avoid zombie?

Tags: python, subprocess

In below code from a Python script I'm spawning another Python script.

I want to run "test_bin" in the background and don't want to call wait or communicate to reap the exit status. If I not used wait/communicate "test_bin" become defunct(zombie) after completion.

Is there any way we can avoid defunct without wait/communicate?

```
import subprocess

test_bin = "/usr/local/bin/test_code.py" # Took 5-10 min to complete
proc_handle = subprocess.Popen( (test_bin, shell=True)
:
:
proc_handle.wait() # don't want to do this.
```

Comment: Whats the issue about `wait/communicate` ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer. I just want to trigger the process.i don't care about the return value. or output.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix-like systems, it is enough to ignore `SIGCHLD` for child processes to never become zombies. So you could do:

```
import subprocess
import signal

test_bin = "/usr/local/bin/test_code.py" # Took 5-10 min to complete
signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)
proc_handle = subprocess.Popen( (test_bin, shell=True)
...
```

Comment: This will not affect Popen ? Because in C language,  we cannot ignore SIGCHLD if we use popen.